# EJB's is not injected in Vaadin BrowserOepener window UI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, vaadin, cdi, vaadin7

I am using Vaadin 7 with CDI. Everything worked perfectly until I wanted to use other UI class in my project for dynamic document generation.

```
@CDIUI(value = "PrintUI")
public static class PrintUI extends UI 
    {    
        @EJB
        MyBean myBean;

        @Override
        protected void init(VaadinRequest request) 
            {
                setContent(new Label(myBean.getHTMLContent(), ContentMode.HTML));
            }
    }

//method somewhere in the main UI class custom component

void printOpenedPage () 
    {
        // Create an opener extension
        BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener(PrintUI.class);
        opener.setFeatures("height=200,width=400,resizable");

        // A button to open the printer-friendly page.
        Button print = new Button("Click to Print");
        opener.extend(print);
    }
```

My problem is that when I open the window I always get NPE because MyBean object in't injected. I tried to use @Inject and @EJB. Also tried to inject a local interface of the class, but no luck. Is it possible to access Stateless ejb objects in UI class that is opened trough BrowserWindowOpener class?

Thanks in advance